# Flask restfull many-to-many

Tags: python, flask, many-to-many, flask-restful

I have an API in python who use flask, flask-restful... and the front is an Angular webapp.
I have a model "Campaign" and a model `Tag` with a relation many-to-many, stocked in the table `Campaigns_Tags` composed by `Id, CampaignId, TagId`.

I want to create/update link between Campaigns and Tags when I update Campaigns.

**JSON**

```
{
 "Name": "MyCampaign",
 "Tags": [2] // List of tags id
}
```

**Python resource**

```
class CampaignsResource(BaseListResource):
        args = parser_new.parse_args()

        # set ClientId (same as current_user) and AuthorId
        args['ClientId'] = session.get('client_id')
        args['AuthorId'] = session.get('id')

        # save object
        new_campaign = self.model.create(**args)


        return new_campaign, 201
```

My models are built my the SQLAlchemy's reflection mechanism.

Can I do it in one api call ? I have to do it by myself ? There is no generic method to fill the table `Campaigns_Tags` ?

I found nothing about many-to-many relationship with flask-restfull if you have some link I'm interreseting. Maybe I misunderstand something, I'm a newbie in python

Answer (score -1):

From my experience, SQLAlchemy does not really support many-to-many relationships directly. I've always had to handle each side of the relationship separately in my code, though it's ok to handle both sides in the same call.

This would make it so that the API caller would think it's a standard many-to-many, and the merging of the two one-to-many's into a single response would be handled by your code.